# how can i change/set default fontfamily in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to change the default font for my app to a custom font. I am able to change it for a component, but is there any way i can set any fontfamily as a default to all the components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recently i had to do the same thing, this is my approach:

- In `App.xaml` add you font as a resource, like

> ```
> <Application.Resources>
> <FontFamily x:Key="CustomFontHelvetica">/MyApp;component/Resource/Helvetica.ttf#Helvetica
> </FontFamily>
> </Application.Resources>
> ```

you should set the properties `Build Action` to `Resource` and `Copy to Output directory` to `copy aways` or `copy if newer`

- and in your page change `FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"` to `FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomFontHelvetica}"`

Just do not overwrite font family property in you controls

Comment: I do not know what is wrong but it does not work for me :/ I have no effect for the whole page, but it works when used in single control.

Answer (score 0):

To use it as default font for the entire application (WP8.1) in App.xaml.cs you can do

`rootFrame.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Tahoma");`