# Where is the best place to set a custom Font as Default for the entire project or VisualTree?

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 7 app/game that needs to use a custom font.

### Example:

Set in the page properties:

> FontFamily=".\Fonts\FontFileName.ttf#FontName"

or directly in the `TextBlock` or `Button` Control.

It becomes messy when a `UserControl` is involved as I need to set `UserControl.FontFamily` attribute/property.

**Is there a place where I can set it once and it applies to all the controls in my Project or VisualTree?**

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569986/how-can-i-change-set-default-fontfamily-in-windows-phone-8/18571382#18571382

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font family of all the controls by using the App.Resources by styling implicitly as,

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Give your font name here" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Give your font name here" />
        </Style>
        --------
        --------
        Similarly set the style for all the controls you have used in your app
        --------
        --------
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Set the style for all the controls,whatever you are using in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Blend to create a copy of the default templates of the controls:

1. Right click on the control you want to template (example: `Button`) and select "Edit template" -> "Edit a copy".
2. In the popup, choose "Apply to all" and "Define in Application" in order to apply this template by default on every occurrence of this control.
3. Edit the template to change the Setter property of `FontFamily` to the desired value.

Repeat these steps to every type of control where you want your custom font.
For the `TextBlock` control, you can't edit the Template, so you'll have to use Styles (same idea).